# Session gets lost when you move from one page to other

Tags: java, session, tomcat, cookies, struts2

I am working on a WEB Application. The app creates and stores all the user information on the first page in a session. When I move to the third page the session gets lost. I tried debugging the application the session is stored until the second page but when i move to the third page `ActionContext.getContext().getSession();` returns null. I have set the session timeout to be 60000, so this is not because of a timeout. I am running the application on a Tomcat server. This is what i get after using Live-HTTP headers on firefox.

> Host: localhost:9080 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
>
> Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Referer: http://localhost:9080/App/collect.jsp
>
> Cookie: JSESSIONID=B9EB26ACAC0ACC7B5920B08BA8D2136D
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> Content-Length: 51
>
> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
>
> Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
>
> Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=64E1A2ADED0B3C827BAFF49159075205;
>
> Path=/App/; HttpOnly
>
> Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
>
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> Date: Tue, 09 Jun 2015 23:36:31 GMT Connection: close

Comment: I suggest that you begin your debugging efforts on the *user* side.  Using the debugging facilities built into the web browser, **LQQK** at the actual HTTP exchanges that are taking place, particularly with regard to cookies.  *Does* the client actually store the cookie?  And, *does* the client actually send the same cookie value back to the host with *each and every* HTTP exchange that is part of this sequence?  Does the cookie value remain the same?

Comment: HI @MikeRobinson Thanks for your reply. I just debugged the app using my browser. The cookie remains the same for the first two pages, but for the third page the request cookie changes. I am also getting a 500 internal server error. What do you think could be the problem?

Comment: @Ashay does the thired page in the same domain, do you switch to https ?!